# Does the up arrow not work with an overlay in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm using the newest build (3033) of Sublime Text 3 on OS X 10.8
(This also was happening in build 3021)

I've setup some shortcuts to open an overlay of custom commands using the following in my sublime-keymap file:

```
{ "keys": ["command+f1"], "command": "show_overlay", "args": {"overlay": "command_palette", "text": "PHP"} }
```

I've noticed recently the using the down arrow works to navigate the menu but for some reason the up arrow does not in the way it used to.  *The up arrow works if I down arrow a few items then use up to go back up but it does not work to wrap from the first item to the last item on the overlay.  Sublime Text 2 did (and still does) this on my computer.*

Am I missing something? (it's mildly frustrating)

**UPDATE**

If I do a <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to open the Command Pallet or <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to open the Goto Symbol overlay the up arrow does not work when trying to wrap around the list.  It does in ST2.

**ADDTIONAL UPDATE**
Now on OS X 10.11 and Sublime Text 3 build 3103 and still the up arrow does not work.

I also posted this here: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=12333

Comment: It works for me on Windows, perhaps it's a Mac issue. Does your up arrow work when you open the Command Palette using the regular `command+shift+p` key combination?

Comment: @MattDMo Check my update, I think you may be on to something...

Comment: Sorry @Jason, I just re-read your question more thoroughly. I haven't checked Linux yet, but for me with ST3 on Win and Mac, neither the up arrow nor down arrow wrap, unlike ST2. Have you posted in the [forum](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/) to see if this is intentional, or just hasn't been coded in yet?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is still true (Sublime Text 3 Build 3103). Seems to be a software limitation (feature?) since they encourage the use of the fuzzy search bar that comes with the overlay window.

Also, there is no preference/setting that enables the wrapping.

It would be nice to have it.